# Pass User data from screen to screen - React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to push and get (and print) the data user.uid from LoginAdult screen to HomeParent screen. In the HomeParent screen I want to user it (to pass it to other screens). It would be grateful if anyone helps me !

LoginAdult.js :

```
class LoginAdult extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      email:'',
      password:'',
      isLoading:false,
    }
  }

  LoginPress= async()=>{
    if(this.state.email&& this.state.password)
    {
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password)
    .then(
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>
        var docRef=firebase.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user.uid);
        docRef.get().then((doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              const {status} = doc.data();
              this.checkStatusLogin(status,{user});
              if(status==="Parent")
              { 
                 this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeParent",{user});
              }
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
    }
  }))
    .catch((error)=>{
    }
    )
  }
  }

}
```

HomeParent.js :

```
class HomeParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={

    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const {navigation}=this.props;
    const user=navigation.getParam('user');
  }
 
    render(){
        return(
              <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                <Image source={Logo} style={styles.logo}/>
                <Text style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',margin:40,fontSize:25}}>Home Parent</Text>
              </View>

)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To pass the params you need to do following things in HomeParent,

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);

    const user = this.props.navigation.getParam('user');
    this.state={
    user,
    }
```

But ideally, this is not the standard way, what you can do is to save the userId in AsyncStorage, like `AsyncStorage.setItem('userId');`and to get the userId, you can create a async function in componentDidMount like

```
componentDidMount(){
this.handleData();
}

handleData=async()=>{
const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
}
```

Comment: The function AsyncStorage.setItem('userId') has to be in the LoginAdult screen? Could you explain, how could I use the function handleData() ? How can i use it to print the data?

Comment: One more thing, from user (in your first option), how can I take only the uid?

Comment: Just like user.uid as you are passing the user object directly

Comment: Yes it will be in loginadult screen.

The concern of creating a function handleData is that you can make your code clean. 

componentDidMount works just after the first render. So this function will automatically call and you will get the userid from asyncstorage.

Comment: Isn't it better to use Redux for the user? In order to use it in all his session?

Comment: Redux is used to manage state. But for login functionality you need to understand that the state must not be volatile so it needs to be saved in localstorage so user can use the app without login again

Comment: Every time that I close and open the app without log out, I come back to the session (Im using firebase authentication)
By "localstorage" you mean, use the idea of reducers?
Im beginner it's still confused for me